# Entering directory through unix bash script issue

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Be aware that this code i'm about to post is purposefully not perfect and will not work should there be a a text file in the directory but the full code does have such a check. But the issue is that this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for d in *; do 
    cd $d 
done
```

produces:

```
./test: line 3: cd: 500: No such file or directory 
./test: line 3: cd: 536: No such file or directory 
./test: line 3: cd: 560: No such file or directory 
./test: line 3: cd: 572: No such file or directory 
./test: line 3: cd: out.txt: No such file or directory 
./test: line 3: cd: prob1: No such file or directory 
./test: line 3: cd: problem2: No such file or directory 
./test: line 3: cd: README: No such file or directory 
./test: line 3: cd: test: No such file or directory
```

where 500, 536, 560, and 572 are directories that should be able to be opened. If I do just a cd 500 then I can go into the directory without an issue. But it will not work when I use the automated process in the shell script.

alright so after further going into the program i now have:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1"
for d in */; do
    (
         cd "$d"
        for file in $*; do
        (
                bla="$(head -4 $file|tail -1)"
                cd ~cfb43/cs265/a1
                echo $bla > out.txt
                cd
                cd "$1"
                cd "$d"
        )
        done
        cd "$1"
    )
done
```

and i receive:

```
head: error reading `/home/cfb43/cs265/a1': Is a directory
head: error reading `/home/cfb43/cs265/a1': Is a directory
head: error reading `/home/cfb43/cs265/a1': Is a directory
head: error reading `/home/cfb43/cs265/a1': Is a directory
head: error reading `/home/cfb43/cs265/a1': Is a directory
```

All i want to do is go into a directory and read from a file and get the fourth line of text and print it to out.txt in my folder. I'm not sure why this code is getting stuck at a1 and not atleast 500 or something like that. any further help and i would be very greatful

Answer (score 5):

Because you try to enter the next subdirectory without leaving the previous one. You could do

```
#!/bin/bash 
for d in */; do 
    cd -- "$d"
    # do some stuff
    cd .. 
done
```

or use a subshell

```
#!/bin/bash 
for d in */; do 
    (
        cd -- "$d"
        # do some stuff
    )
done
```

Comment: could you possibly look at the new portion of the question because what you said worked but led to new issues. also why do you have the "--" in the cd command?

Comment: @ColanBiemer The `--` is for guaranteeing that if a directory name starts with `-` (e.g. `-mydir`) it will not be interpreted as an option to the `cd` command, but as a directory name. Regarding your new error message, it looks like you call `head` on a directory. You should check that the operant is a regular file with `if [[ -f "$file" ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure of what you are doing: $* which expands to parameters $1 $2 .. ${!#}

```
for file in $*; do
```

maybe you want: * which expands to files in current directory

```
for file in *; do
```

Another way to do is to never change directory:

```
for file in */*;do
   head -4 "$file" | tail -1 >> ~cfb43/cs265/a1/out.txt
done
```

and another way to do

```
head -4 | tail -1
```

with sed

```
sed n '4{p;q}'
```

with awk

```
awk 'NR==4{print;exit}'
```

with perl

```
perl -ne 'if($.==4){print;exit}'
```

Comment: when i did that i got head: cannot open `*' for reading: No such file or directory where i then had to exit out of it